# In yii how to json_encoded multiple records

Tags: json, yii

i am creating project in yii+extjs. I am having poll table with pollid and pollQuestion. Option table is having pollid and options. Now during publishing question i am retrieving question from poll table and options of that question from option table. and sending this data in json_encoded format. i had desgined function as-

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new poll();
    $model->pollId=4;
    $record1=poll::model()->findByPk($model->pollId); 
    //$data = $record1->getAttributes();
    $data= $record1->getAttributes(array('pollId','pollQuestion'));
     foreach ($record1->polloptions as $option) 
     { 
        $data = array_merge($data, $option->with('pollId')-                      >getAttributes());
     }
      //echo $data;
      echo CJSON::encode($data);
}
```

Option table is having multiple options for same question. But by above method it is displaying only last option inserted in option table instead of displaying all options of same question. So how to display all options of same question.Please help me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you could try:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new poll();
    $model->pollId=4;
    $record1=poll::model()->findByPk($model->pollId); 
    //$data = $record1->getAttributes();
    $data= $record1->getAttributes(array('pollId','pollQuestion'));
     foreach ($record1->polloptions as $option) 
     { 
        $optionArray = $option->getAttributes()
        //if the 2 arrays havn't the same indexes
        //this way u keep the key indexes
        $data = $data + $optionArray;
        //if the 2 arrays could have the same indexes
        $data = array_push($data, $optionArray);
     }
      //echo $data;
      echo CJSON::encode($data);
}
```

Comment: Than sir for reply...i made changes as per above. But still its displaying only lastly inserted option into table.Its not displaying all options of same question.

Comment: try to do a var_dump($record1->polloptions) to see if the array has all the records, maybe the rpoblem is elsewhere (just to be sure that the problem come from the foreach lines)

Comment: After doing var_dump($record1->polloptions), its showing all options retrieved in it. But when i am doing echo CJSON::encode($data),its displaying only last option inserted.

Comment: Hum I don't know what could be wrong, if you do $data[] =$optionArray; Are all the option in the $data array?